# Replacing a SimpleString inside a libcst function definition? (dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'body')

Tags: python, replace, docstring, libcst

### Context

While trying to use the `libcst` module, I am experiencing some difficulties updating a documentation of a function.

### MWE

To reproduce the error, the following minimal working example (MWE) is included:

```py
from libcst import (  # type: ignore[import]
    Expr,
    FunctionDef,
    IndentedBlock,
    MaybeSentinel,
    SimpleStatementLine,
    SimpleString,
    parse_module,
)

original_content: str = """
\"\"\"Example python file with a function.\"\"\"


from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def add_three(*, x: int) -> int:
    \"\"\"ORIGINAL This is a new docstring core.
    that consists of multiple lines. It also has an empty line inbetween.

    Here is the emtpy line.\"\"\"
    return x + 2

"""
new_docstring_core: str = """\"\"\"This is a new docstring core.
    that consists of multiple lines. It also has an empty line inbetween.

    Here is the emtpy line.\"\"\""""


def replace_docstring(
    original_content: str, func_name: str, new_docstring: str
) -> str:
    """Replaces the docstring in a Python function."""
    module = parse_module(original_content)
    for node in module.body:
        if isinstance(node, FunctionDef) and node.name.value == func_name:
            print("Got function node.")
            # print(f'node.body={node.body}')
            if isinstance(node.body, IndentedBlock):
                if isinstance(node.body.body[0], SimpleStatementLine):
                    simplestatementline: SimpleStatementLine = node.body.body[
                        0
                    ]

                    print("Got SimpleStatementLine")
                    print(f"simplestatementline={simplestatementline}")

                    if isinstance(simplestatementline.body[0], Expr):
                        print(
                            f"simplestatementline.body={simplestatementline.body}"
                        )

                        simplestatementline.body = (
                            Expr(
                                value=SimpleString(
                                    value=new_docstring,
                                    lpar=[],
                                    rpar=[],
                                ),
                                semicolon=MaybeSentinel.DEFAULT,
                            ),
                        )


replace_docstring(
    original_content=original_content,
    func_name="add_three",
    new_docstring=new_docstring_core,
)
print("done")
```

### Error:

Running `python mwe.py` yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/git/Hiveminds/jsonmodipy/mwe0.py", line 68, in <module>
    replace_docstring(
  File "/home/name/git/Hiveminds/jsonmodipy/mwe0.py", line 56, in replace_docstring
    simplestatementline.body = (
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 4, in __setattr__
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'body'
```

### Question

How can one replace the docstring of a function named: `add_three` in some Python code `file_content` using the libcst module?

### Partial Solution

I found the following solution for a basic example, however, I did not test it on different functions inside classes, with typed arguments, typed returns etc.

```py
from pprint import pprint
import libcst as cst
import libcst.matchers as m


src = """\
import foo
from a.b import foo_method


class C:
    def do_something(self, x):
        \"\"\"Some first line documentation
        Some second line documentation

        Args:something.
        \"\"\"
        return foo_method(x)
"""
new_docstring:str = """\"\"\"THIS IS A NEW DOCSTRING
        Some first line documentation
        Some second line documentation

        Args:somethingSTILLCHANGED.
        \"\"\""""

class ImportFixer(cst.CSTTransformer):
    def leave_SimpleStatementLine(self, orignal_node, updated_node):
        """Replace imports that match our criteria."""
        
        if m.matches(updated_node.body[0], m.Expr()):
            expr=updated_node.body[0]
            if m.matches(expr.value, m.SimpleString()):
                simplestring=expr.value
                print(f'GOTT={simplestring}')
                return updated_node.with_changes(body=[
                    cst.Expr(value=cst.SimpleString(value=new_docstring))
                ])
        return updated_node

source_tree = cst.parse_module(src)
transformer = ImportFixer()
modified_tree = source_tree.visit(transformer)

print("Original:")
print(src)
print("\n\n\n\nModified:")
print(modified_tree.code)
```

For example, this partial solution fails on:

```py
src = """\
import foo
from a.b import foo_method


class C:
    def do_something(self, x):
        \"\"\"Some first line documentation
        Some second line documentation

        Args:something.
        \"\"\"
        return foo_method(x)
    
def do_another_thing(y:List[str]) -> int:
    \"\"\"Bike\"\"\"
    return 1
    """
```

because the solution does not verify the name of the function in which the `SimpleString` occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why were you getting the "FrozenInstanceError" ?**

As you saw, the CST produced by `libcst` is a graph made of immutable nodes (each one representing a part of the Python language). If you want to change a node, you actually need to make a new copy of it.
This is done using `node.with_changes()` method.

So you could do this in your first code snippet.
However, there are more "elegant" ways to achieve this, partly documented in [libcst's tutorial](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), as you just started doing in your partial solution.

**How can one replace the docstring of a function named: add_three in some Python code file_content using the libcst module?**

Use the libcst.CSTTransformer to navigate your way through:

1. You need to find, in the CST, the node representing your function (`libcst.FunctionDef`)
2. You then need to find the node representing the documentation of your function (`licst.SimpleString`)
3. Update this documentation node

```
import libcst

class DocUpdater(libcst.CSTTransformer):
    """Upodate the docstring of the function `add_three`"""
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._docstring: str | None = None

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node: libcst.FunctionDef) -> Optional[bool]:
        """Trying to find the node defining function `add_three`,
         and get its docstring"""
        if node.name.value == 'add_three':
            self._docstring = f'"""{node.get_docstring(clean=False)}"""'
            """Unfortunatly, get_docstring doesn't return the exact docstring
            node value: you need to add the docstring's triple quotes"""
            return True
        return False

    def leave_SimpleString(
        self, original_node: libcst.SimpleString, updated_node: libcst.SimpleString
    ) -> libcst.BaseExpression:
        """Trying to find the node defining the docstring
        of your function, and update the docstring"""
        if original_node.value == self._docstring:
            return updated_node.with_changes(value='"""My new docstring"""')

        return updated_node
```

And finally:

```
test = r'''
import foo
from a.b import foo_method


class C:
    def add_three(self, x):
        """Some first line documentation
        Some second line documentation

        Args:something.
        """
        return foo_method(x)

def do_another_thing(y: list[str]) -> int:
    """Bike"""
    return 1
'''

cst = libcst.parse_module(test)
updated_cst = cst.visit(DocUpdater())

print(updated_cst.code)
```

Output:

```
import foo
from a.b import foo_method


class C:
    def add_three(self, x):
        """My new docstring"""
        return foo_method(x)

def do_another_thing(y: list[str]) -> int:
    """Bike"""
    return 1
```

Comment: Magnificent, thank you for your explanation, reference, example and output!